# sklearn ColumnTransformer: Duplicate columns in transformers

Tags: python, scikit-learn, pipeline

I am looking for a help building a data preprocessing pipleline using sklearn's ColumnTransformer functions.

Currently my pipleline looks something like this:

```
from scipy.stats.mstats import winsorize 
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer 
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer

ColumnTransformer(remainder='passthrough',
                  transformers=[
                              ('Winsorize', FunctionTransformer(winsorize,
                                                     kw_args={'axis': 0, 'inplace': False, 'limits': [0, 0.01]}), ['feat_1','feat_2']),
                                ('num_impute', SimpleImputer(strategy='median'), ['feat_3', 'feat_4']),
                                ])
```

Note that each transformer is provided a unique set of features.

The issue I am encountering is how to apply stacked analysis for the same features. For example,

```
ColumnTransformer(remainder='passthrough',
                  transformers=[
                              ('Winsorize', FunctionTransformer(winsorize,
                                                     kw_args={'axis': 0, 'inplace': False, 'limits': [0, 0.01]}), ['feat_1','feat_2']),
                                ('num_impute', SimpleImputer(strategy='median'), ['feat_1', 'feat_2', 'feat_3']),
                                ])
```

Note that feat_1 and feat_2 where provided for both transformers.

a pipeline like this will create duplicate columns for feat_1 and feat_2 (Two columns based on Winsorize, and two columns based on num_impute)

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you can use two `ColumnTransformer` and one `FeatureUnion` to achieve what you want. One `ColumnTransformer` will have `remainder='passthrough'` to keep all columns except the ones being transformed, and the other will have `remainder='drop'`. That could look like this:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion

ct1 = ColumnTransformer(
    remainder='passthrough',
    transformers=[(
        'Winsorize', FunctionTransformer(
            winsorize,
            kw_args={'axis': 0, 'inplace': False, 'limits': [0, 0.01]}
        ), 
        ['feat_1', 'feat_2']
    )]
)

ct2 = ColumnTransformer(
    remainder='drop',
    transformers=[('num_impute', SimpleImputer(strategy='median'), ['feat_1', 'feat_2', 'feat_3'])],
)

union = FeatureUnion([('ct1', ct1), ('ct2', ct2)])
```

Comment: per sklearn doc: "A FeatureUnion takes a list of transformer objects. During fitting, each of these is fit to the data independently. The transformers are applied in parallel, and the feature matrices they output are concatenated side-by-side into a larger matrix" It appears that this will concatenate the transformations rather than applying then in a series

Comment: Oh ok, you want to impute after the `winsorize` step?

Comment: you are Correct.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Pipeline` as the transformer for each column set if you need multiple transformations applied to a column.

```py
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

imputer = SimpleImputer(strategy="median")
winsorize = FunctionTransformer(
  winsorize, kw_args={"axis": 0, "inplace": False, "limits": [0, 0.01]})

ColumnTransformer([
  ("F1,F2", Pipeline([
    ("Winsorize", winsorize),
    ("Impute", imputer)
  ]), ["feat_1","feat_2"]),
  ("F3", imputer, ["feat_3"])
], remainder="passthrough")
```